# Is it possible to use the listview control used by the windows explorer?

Tags: .net, windows, listview

I want to a list view that support small images, list, details and also large icons and very large icons.

The windows explorer list view can show image nodes until 256x256. Is it possible doing it with .NET?

**NOTE**: I don't want to embedd the windows explorer in a .NET application. I only want to use the same control that uses the windows explorer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this freeware component: [Better ListView Express](http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview-express).

It supports images of any size. There is also sample showing dynamically resizing items (Control+MouseWeel) as in the Windows Explorer.

The Better ListView has been designed to conform more to modern Windows Explorer than to regular .NET ListView.

There is also a full version available with many interesting features.